# Как взять следующее сообщение пользователя aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

В telebot этот метод выглядит так `bot.register_next_step_handler`.

Как взять следующее сообщение пользователя в aiogram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать машину состояний.

```py
сlass Form(StatesGroup):
    peremennaya = State() # Задаем состояние

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправь свое сообщение:')
    await Form.peremennaya.set() # Устанавливаем состояние

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.a) # Принимаем состояние
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as proxy: # Устанавливаем состояние ожидания
    a['peremennaya'] = message.text
    await state.finish() # Выключаем состояние
```

Где в кавычках после переменной a должно находиться переменная, которой названо состояние, в данном случае `peremennaya`.

Comment: Откуда взялось Form.a, что это вообще?

Answer (score 2):

Дорогой @Blazzerrr! В aiogram отсутствует реализация в виде next_step_handler(), которая есть в telebot, но существует более интересная и функциональная штука как States.

Посмотрите [официальную документацию](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/docs/lesson_14/).

Answer (score 1):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import config
import logging

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def do_something(message: Message):
    return
```

Это если нужен текст, для файлов указывай нужный content_types

Comment: Я немного не то имел в виду Здесь из этого хэндлера я могу получить любое, то есть первое сообщение от пользователя, а как допустим сделать так, чтобы пользователь отправил команду /command
После нее бот отправляет текст "Отправь ниже свое сообщение"
И вот здесь мне нужно взять это сообщение и например добавить в БД
В telebot это можно сделать как раз с помощью bot.register_next_step_handler

Comment: Ты можешь использовать машину состояний. Очень полезная вещь

После отправления команды "/command" ты меняешь состояние и ловишь сообщение пользователя, после чего снова меняешь состояние

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html