# Как выполнять одну функцию после другой? Python, aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, inline

У меня есть бот-тест, который должен последовательно присылать человеку вопросы с кнопками и писать правильно / неправильно
Как кидать вопросы не все сразу, а по одному, чтобы вопрос приходил когда пользователь ответил на пред вопрос
Пытался сделать так, не присылает след функцию

````
@dp.message_handler(regexp='Начать тест',content_types="text")
async def a(message:types.Message):
    await message.answer("Что обозначает тег a?",reply_markup=taga_kb)
    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'right_answera')
    async def raona(message:types.Message):
        global count
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,text="Правильный ответ!")
        count+=1
    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'notright_answera')
    async def nrona(message:types.Message):
        global count
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,text="Неправильный ответ.")
async def nextquestion(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer("Что обозначает тег div?", reply_markup=tagdiv_kb)
        @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'right_answerdiv')
        async def raondiv(message: types.Message):
            global count
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Правильный ответ!")
            count += 1
            @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'notright_answerdiv')
            async def nrondiv(message: types.Message):
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Неправильный ответ.")```
````

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1159225/234134

Comment: у меня инлайн кнопки, нужно через data

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри на этот ответ, там используется машина состояний в aiogram, поэкспериментируй с кодом

[Как взять следующее сообщение пользователя aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144911/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-aiogram?rq=1)

Вот урок, который мне помог разобраться с этим в свое время.
https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter3.html

```
class Form(StateGroup):
    name = State()
    age = State()

@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands=['setstate'])
async def process_setstate_command(message: types.Message):
    Form.name.set()
    await message.answer('Введите имя')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.name)
async def process_setstate_name(message: types.Message):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    Form.next()
    await message.answer('Введите возраст')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.age)
async def process_setstate_age(message: types.Message):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['age'] = message.text
        await message.answer(f'Вас зовут {data['name']}, вам {data['age']} лет.')
    state.finish()
```

Вот небольшой пример, который вы можете переделать под себя.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/762402)