# Как получить второе сообщение telegram bot aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Я хочу сделать проверку на следующее сообщение после команды /weather.
Каким образом я могу это сделать?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
async def repeat_all_messages(message):
    city = message.text[9:]
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, weather_now(city))
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Показать более подробную информацию (Да/Нет)")
    # Проверка на сообщение:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, weather_hourly())
```

Comment: Ищите по запросу *state machine aiogram*. Вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1144911/384202

Answer (score 0):

Код:

```
#Импорты
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

#Класс со состояниями
class ms_to_users(StatesGroup):
    text = State()

#Сам код
async def mailing(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(Показать более подробную информацию (Да/Нет))
    await ms_to_users.text.set()

async def get_usr_text(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    text = f"{message.text}"
    if text == "Да":
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, weather_hourly())
    else:
        await message.answer("Ну как хочешь")
```

Но я бы использовал просто inline-кнопки "Да" и "Нет"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]