# Как сообщение пользователя положить в переменную бот aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Бот должен был проверять id пользователя на присутствие в списке админов, а после давать возможность отправить сообщение, которое в последствии бот отправлял бы в канал. Проблема, только в том что я не знаю как сделать, так чтобы он мог записать сообщение пользователя в переменную **в цикле**

Вот код который есть на данный момент

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher

from config import channel_id, user_id
from create_bot import dp, bot

@dp.message_handler(commands="admin")
async def get_5_ria(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == user_id:
        await message.answer("Напишите своё сообщение")
        # @dp.message_handler() - моя попытка сделать это при помощи хендлера
        await bot.send_message(channel_id, message.text)
    else:
        pass
def register_handler_admin(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(get_5_ria, commands="admin")
```

Comment: и что конкретно у вас не получается? какие-то реализации уже есть?

Comment: Не получается, засунуть в цикл функцию, которая при поступлении нового сообщения от пользователя будет переносить его в переменную

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как взять следующее сообщение пользователя aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144911/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-aiogram)